# Jack audio server - can start on CLI but not as a systemd service

Tags: audio, systemd

I try to start jack server on boot

**I can run it manually** on the desktop:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /usr/bin/jackd -r -d alsa -r 44100
jackdmp 1.9.12
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2016 Grame.
Copyright 2016-2017 Filipe Coelho.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
JACK server starting in non-realtime mode
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for capture. Falling back to playback-only mode
configuring for 44100Hz, period = 1024 frames (23.2 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 16bit little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
Jack main caught signal 2
Released audio card Audio0
audio_reservation_finish
```

**but once I try to run it via systemd**, I get

```
Failed to connect to session bus for device reservation: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
To bypass device reservation via session bus, set JACK_NO_AUDIO_RESERVATION=1 prior to starting jackd.
```

just like if jack server needed the X server to be running

here is my systemd startup script:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/systemd/system/jackd.service
[Unit]
Description=Jack audio server 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
PrivateTmp=true
ExecStart=/usr/bin/jackd -r -d alsa -r 44100
```

- I tried exporting **JACK_NO_AUDIO_RESERVATION=1** before running **sudo systemctl start jackd**
- I tried to find the answer on google or a tutorial, but nobody as done this before apparently

how do I run jack audio server at startup with systemd ?

thanks for the time you'll spent on this question

Comment: Have you try to set variable in your unit file : `[Service]
Environment="JACK_NO_AUDIO_RESERVATION=1"` ? followed by your other conf `ExecStart=/usr/bin/jackd -r -d alsa -r 44100`

Comment: yes,indeed jack is running, now I need to figure why qjackctl does not see it running

Comment: qjackctl  is a graphical interface ? The  X server is require I think. Try to set `Environment="Display...."` variable in this case ?

Comment: no I mean, jack is running now (from systemd config) but qjackctl does not find it running "Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory"

Comment: Maybe try to search command line option for /usr/bin/jackd and socket listening or check qjackctl parameters.

Comment: that's odd, when I run zynaddsubfx(jack), it launches jack automaticaly and qjackctl finds it running

Comment: and if I run jack from the cli, qjackctl (ran in another terminal) sees jack running too...hmm....so if I try sudo qjackctl, it crashed the PI...

Comment: What is the output of syslog in this case ?

Comment: I had to setup permissions for RT priorities, yet it's not working, but I realised that jack running RT on the RPI4 is really slow, I use puredata to generate a 440hz signal, and it sounds more la 10hz, so I'll avoid using RT for now

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Ephemeral

here is the answer:

to disable the X dependency issue, I added **environment="JACK_NO_AUDIO_RESERVATION=1"** in the systemd config

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/systemd/system/jackd.service
[Unit]
Description=Jack audio server 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
PrivateTmp=true
Environment="JACK_NO_AUDIO_RESERVATION=1"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/jackd -r -d alsa -r 44100
```